# What is the key in a KeysCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I have the following ASP.NET code

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    if (!key.StartsWith("form"))
    {
        log.WriteLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to see a log entry something like this...

```
amount: €623.66
customer: 56789
```

I don't expect, but do get, lines beginning with "form" in the log

```
formdata: sample data
formlayout: html
```

What is wrong with the code?  If the `key` in a `KeysCollection` is not a `string` then it would be reasonable to expect that the string key in `Request.Form.Keys wouldn't compile, but it does?  Weird (at least to me!)

Comment: Your code seems correct. Are you sure that your form keys don't include funny characters that are not caught by the StartsWith("form") comparison? Maybe try something along the lines of *if (!key.StartsWith("form", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))*

Comment: Thanks matk.  Was missing the check for case sensitivity (doh!)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing event checking for page postback before looping through `Keys`

Try this code block it is working fine for me:

```
    if (IsPostBack == true)
    {
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            if (!key.StartsWith("form"))
            {
                log.WriteLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to log (most) keys regardless of whether the page is posted back or not.  Errors are handled elsewhere in my code.  Why would event checking matter?

Comment: because in this event you get all keys of the form.

Comment: According to Microsoft IsPostBack... "Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback."  In my mind it has nothing to do with preparing the Form object.  Anyway, I want to log where IsPostBack ==true and IsPostBack == false so I tried that and it failed to do as expected, without error.

Comment: @cymorg It may be possibility that your aspx page may contain some junk characters.So can you post code of your aspx page here?

Comment: @cymorg you are not getting any result even if you are postback the page?

Comment: I am posting a form to the page.  All form values are currently being logged.  I want to log most, but not all, form values.  I have tried key != "formdata" (which is one of the values i want to exclude.  It seems that although key is defined as a string it isn't behaving as one!  Very strange.

Comment: ASPX is all written from code behind.  Nothing to show!  I've worked around the problem by using this... if (key != "formdata" && key != "formcontent")  It's not a great solution but it works.  Case sensitivity will be an issue.